# Solidity and React: cannot use method.call() for view functions in a contract

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, truffle, ganache

I was trying to make a to-do list using react as my front-end and solidity as my backend. I used Truffle and Ganache to test it. I successfully set up the private blockchain and imported multiple accounts from Ganache. However, whenever I use method.call() in my react app, it throws the following error:

```
index.js:298 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? 
You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at ABICoder.push../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (index.js:298)
    at ABICoder.push../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParameters (index.js:285)
    at Contract.push../node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js.Contract._decodeMethodReturn (index.js:470)
    at Method.outputFormatter (index.js:760)
    at Method.push../node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js.Method.formatOutput (index.js:147)
    at sendTxCallback (index.js:523)
    at cb (util.js:689)
    at Item.push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run (browser.js:153)
    at drainQueue (browser.js:123)
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I checked the abi and contract address, but they all seem to be correct. Could anyone please tell me what causes the error and how I can fix it?
Here is my solidity and react code:

Solidity (contract):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Todolist {
  string[][] lists;
  mapping (address => uint) public ownerToListId;
  mapping (address => bool) ownerHasList;

  function addToList(string calldata item) external{
    if (!ownerHasList[msg.sender]) {
      // newList = newList.push(item);
      lists.push([item]);
      ownerToListId[msg.sender] = lists.length - 1;
    } else {
      lists[ownerToListId[msg.sender]].push(item);
    }
  }

  function getList() external view returns(string[] memory) {
    return lists[ownerToListId[msg.sender]];
  }
}
```

React (app.js) :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Web3 from "web3";
import { todolistAbi } from "./abi/abis";
import "./App.css";

const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
const contractAddr = "0x75e4f59aBA61e780Accf573Ce632C2f31B534056";
const TodolistContract = new web3.eth.Contract(todolistAbi, contractAddr);

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(["placeholder"]);
  // const [getNumber, setGetNumber] = useState(0x00);
  const [itemToAdd, setItemToAdd] = useState("");
  const getList = async () => {
    const list = await TodolistContract.methods.getList().call();
    console.log(list);
    setList(list.map((item) => <li>{item}</li>));
  };

  const addToList = async () => {
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
    const account = accounts[0];
    const gas = await TodolistContract.methods
      .addToList(itemToAdd)
      .estimateGas();
    await TodolistContract.methods
      .addToList(itemToAdd)
      .send({ from: account, gas });
    console.log("a");

    await getList();
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <div>
          <ul>{list}</ul>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type='text' onChange={(e) => setItemToAdd(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={addToList} type='button'>
          get the list!
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

truffle-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*", // Any network (default: none)
      from: "0xfbfaf75dea69c388f45d20d5aab7b947072d8416",
      gas: 18000000,
    },
  },

  mocha: {
  },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.0",
    },
  },
};
```

I am having the error when I call getList function in react...
"const list = await TodolistContract.methods.getList().call();"

Comment: Check the contract address again. you are hardcoding it. Do you change it when you deploy the contract again?. See this question for the similar kind of problem and procedure for providing the correct values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68760210/returned-values-arent-valid-did-it-run-out-of-gas-web3-1-5-0-and-sol-0-5-15/68772507?noredirect=1#comment121574604_68772507

Answer (score 0):

```
function getList() external view returns(string[] memory) {
    return lists[ownerToListId[msg.sender]];
  }
```

when you call this function on react side, you have to send account and  values. Who is calling this function? caller of this function should be manager, msg.sender.