# Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? web3 1.5.0 and sol-0.5.15

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js, truffle, metamask

I am new to the field of blockchain and ethereum. I have been trying to create a simple testing network using truffle and ganache where I created a new workplace in truffle and tried to build a quick react frontend app to connect to the ethereum using Web3.

Everything works fine. I did install the MetaMask and created a new network to the port:7545 and every change that happened to the ganache affected the MetaMask.

This is the code of web3js.

```
const web3 = new Web3("http://127.0.0.1:7545")
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    setaccount(accounts)
    const todoList = new web3.eth.Contract(TodoList.abi, ADRESS);
    console.log('here the todo contract');
    console.log(todoList);
    setTodoList(todoList)
    const taskCount = await todoList.methods.taskCount().call()
```

The contacts show fine and the account also.
but when I tried to call the function, it showed me this error which confused me.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node that is not fully synced.
    at ABICoder.push../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (index.js:297)
    at ABICoder.push../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParameters (index.js:284)
    at Contract.push../node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js.Contract._decodeMethodReturn (index.js:469)
    at Method.outputFormatter (index.js:759)
    at Method.push../node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js.Method.formatOutput (index.js:147)
    at sendTxCallback (index.js:523)
    at index.js:307
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (index.js:98)
push../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParametersWith @ index.js:297
push../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParameters @ index.js:284
push../node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js.Contract._decodeMethodReturn @ index.js:469
outputFormatter @ index.js:759
push../node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js.Method.formatOutput @ index.js:147
sendTxCallback @ index.js:523
(anonymous) @ index.js:307
request.onreadystatechange @ index.js:98
async function (async)
loadBlockchainDate @ App.js:36
(anonymous) @ App.js:20
invokePassiveEffectCreate @ react-dom.development.js:23487
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23574
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:417
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:390
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:157
```

and this is my solidiy contracts

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract TodoList {
  uint public taskCount = 0;

constructor() public {
     createTask("Check out dappuniversity.com");
   }

  struct Task {
    uint id;
    string content;
    bool completed;
  }

  mapping(uint => Task) public tasks;

  function createTask(string memory _content) public {
    taskCount ++;
    tasks[taskCount] = Task(taskCount, _content, false);
  }

}
```

and this is the ABI.

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "taskCount",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "tasks",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "id",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "content",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "completed",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "_content",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "createTask",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

and this is the contract that I get from web3 when connecting to the abi and address.

```
Contract
BatchRequest: ƒ ()
clearSubscriptions: ƒ (keepIsSyncing)
currentProvider: (...)
defaultAccount: (...)
defaultBlock: (...)
defaultChain: (...)
defaultCommon: (...)
defaultHardfork: (...)
events: {allEvents: ƒ}
extend: ƒ (extension)
givenProvider: Proxy {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: 100, _log: a, _state: {…}, …}
handleRevert: (...)
methods:
0x8d977672: ƒ ()
0x111002aa: ƒ ()
0xb6cb58a5: ƒ ()
createTask: ƒ ()
createTask(string): ƒ ()
taskCount: ƒ ()
taskCount(): ƒ ()
tasks: ƒ ()
tasks(uint256): ƒ ()
[[Prototype]]: Object
options: {}
providers: {WebsocketProvider: ƒ, HttpProvider: ƒ, IpcProvider: ƒ}
setProvider: ƒ ()
setRequestManager: manager => {…}
transactionBlockTimeout: (...)
transactionConfirmationBlocks: (...)
transactionPollingTimeout: (...)
_address: "0x8c0199C5D6e4B22A1948358F1bf48dD095Ae5300"
_jsonInterface: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
_provider: HttpProvider {withCredentials: false, timeout: 0, headers: undefined, agent: undefined, connected: true, …}
_requestManager: RequestManager {provider: HttpProvider, providers: {…}, subscriptions: Map(0)}
get currentProvider: () => { return pkg._provider; }
set currentProvider: value => { return pkg.setProvider(value); }
get defaultAccount: ƒ ()
set defaultAccount: ƒ (val)
get defaultBlock: ƒ ()
set defaultBlock: ƒ (val)
get defaultChain: ƒ ()
set defaultChain: ƒ (val)
get defaultCommon: ƒ ()
set defaultCommon: ƒ (val)
get defaultHardfork: ƒ ()
set defaultHardfork: ƒ (val)
get handleRevert: ƒ ()
set handleRevert: ƒ (val)
get transactionBlockTimeout: ƒ ()
set transactionBlockTimeout: ƒ (val)
get transactionConfirmationBlocks: ƒ ()
set transactionConfirmationBlocks: ƒ (val)
get transactionPollingTimeout: ƒ ()
set transactionPollingTimeout: ƒ (val)
[[Prototype]]: Contract
```

When I did the `truffle version` I get this

```
Truffle v5.4.3 (core: 5.4.3)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.17.0
Web3.js v1.5.0
```

and I installed the web3 version 1.5.1 and also tried 1.5.0 but still faced the same error.

this is the tutorial that I am following https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/ethereum-dapp-react-tutorial

Edit : I am  using  the Ganache GUI and my Metamask custom sitting is.
[image]

**The Issue** : I used the address of the node instead of the address of the contract that after I applied the `truffle migrate --reset all` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried the same code using truffle and ganache and it works for me. The only difference is that i am running ganache on port `8545` and connecting  metamask with that port in url. I believe that you are providing somewhat incorrect values here `const todoList = new web3.eth.Contract(TodoList.abi, ADRESS);`

Make Sure that your contract's **abi** and **address** is correct. Read details about instantiation of contract object with correct values [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html)

Here is how i am reading the JSON file:

`const TodoList = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/TodoList.json', 'utf8'));`.

I am simply extracting the abi from it just like your code. For Contract Address part, I get the address manually from the output console after running `truffle migrate --reset all`.

After this you will get a receipt information in console like this

```
Replacing 'TodoList'
   --------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x00d16b5ee5f4ddad354543a100d7c730114f5668d5f3b35f1a2306764335c32d
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x5592F579627C9123F2EB77429B3E6e66891C6a9A
   > block number:        11
   > block timestamp:     1628967561
   > account:             0xa0aC73a479e9B6F5b5Ee0b0Fd241bbb1D83C5ec2
   > balance:             99.95728292
   > gas used:            363127 (0x58a77)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00726254 ETH
```

You need to copy the **contract address** and put it like this: `"0x5592F579627C9123F2EB77429B3E6e66891C6a9A"`

**truffle-config.js** file: Use this configuration for compiling the contracts

```
/**
 * Use this file to configure your truffle project. It's seeded with some
 * common settings for different networks and features like migrations,
 * compilation and testing. Uncomment the ones you need or modify
 * them to suit your project as necessary.
 *
 * More information about configuration can be found at:
 *
 * trufflesuite.com/docs/advanced/configuration
 *
 * To deploy via Infura you'll need a wallet provider (like @truffle/hdwallet-provider)
 * to sign your transactions before they're sent to a remote public node. Infura accounts
 * are available for free at: infura.io/register.
 *
 * You'll also need a mnemonic - the twelve word phrase the wallet uses to generate
 * public/private key pairs. If you're publishing your code to GitHub make sure you load this
 * phrase from a file you've .gitignored so it doesn't accidentally become public.
 *
 */

// const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
//
// const fs = require('fs');
// const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Networks define how you connect to your ethereum client and let you set the
   * defaults web3 uses to send transactions. If you don't specify one truffle
   * will spin up a development blockchain for you on port 9545 when you
   * run `develop` or `test`. You can ask a truffle command to use a specific
   * network from the command line, e.g
   *
   * $ truffle test --network <network-name>
   */

  networks: {
    // Useful for testing. The `development` name is special - truffle uses it by default
    // if it's defined here and no other network is specified at the command line.
    // You should run a client (like ganache-cli, geth or parity) in a separate terminal
    // tab if you use this network and you must also set the `host`, `port` and `network_id`
    // options below to some value.
    //
    development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*"       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    // Another network with more advanced options...
    // advanced: {
    // port: 8777,             // Custom port
    // network_id: 1342,       // Custom network
    // gas: 6000000,           // Gas sent with each transaction (default: ~6700000)
    // gasPrice: 20000000000,  // 20 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
    // from: <address>,        // Account to send txs from (default: accounts[0])
    // websocket: true        // Enable EventEmitter interface for web3 (default: false)
    // },
    // Useful for deploying to a public network.
    // NB: It's important to wrap the provider as a function.
    // ropsten: {
    // provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID`),
    // network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
    // gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
    // confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
    // timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
    // skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    // },
    // Useful for private networks
    // private: {
    // provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://network.io`),
    // network_id: 2111,   // This network is yours, in the cloud.
    // production: true    // Treats this network as if it was a public net. (default: false)
    // }
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.0",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      docker: false,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
       optimizer: {
         enabled: false,
         runs: 200
       },
       evmVersion: "byzantium"
      }
    }
  },

  // Truffle DB is currently disabled by default; to enable it, change enabled: false to enabled: true
  //
  // Note: if you migrated your contracts prior to enabling this field in your Truffle project and want
  // those previously migrated contracts available in the .db directory, you will need to run the following:
  // $ truffle migrate --reset --compile-all

  db: {
    enabled: false
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , did you use ganache-cil to run it in port 8545 ? because I used the genech GUI the default port is 7545 . about the abi I really just copied the abi from the TodoList.json I am not sure if it generated the correct one or not and the likewise the address takes it from the same Json file . also if the connection of the MetaMask was incorrect , It did not change when the ganache changed ? .

Comment: I don't know whats your connection status with Metamask is. but you stated that it reflected changes so i assumed that its working fine. You can also further check by importing the first account of ganache in Metamask. Just get the private key of the first account from ganache-cli console and paste it in Metamask. Make sure that correct balance is also shown in Metamask after account is created. Its even better if you run ganache-cli with a mnemonic with a -m "string" flag. In that way the same accounts will be created from the mnemonic to use the same account in Metamask

Comment: And yes. I gave a port  flag -p 8545 while running ganache-cli. I dont think port number is the problem assuming that you have used custom RPC settings in Metamask correctly. About the ABI and Contract Address part. this needs to be valid. I am passing the ABI in the same way like yours after reading from JSON file. This seems ok since it needs a JSON interface for ABI. For address part, I entered it manually like this "0xD90d46Ae7427933760A52FE06Ba13C443A4E720C" after deploying the contract. And i believe this is where you are having the issue. Check the output of ABI and Address to confirm

Comment: The Address in the MetaMask is the same one in the web3 contrast right ? because I have added a "0x8c0199C5D6e4B22A1948358F1bf48dD095Ae5300'' after the ABI . Really annoying. I do not know where the problem comes from . :"(

Comment: Edit your question and share your Metamask settings. You must be using Custom RPC

Comment: Also, when you run the ganache-cli. which port does it start on?. is it 7545 or 8545 because ganache default port is 8545

Comment: I saw your updated question. Now start your ganache-cli like this and then check. ganache-cli -p 7545 --chainId 1337. if it doesnt work, then you are most definitely providing the wrong values and format for ABI and Address. I will edit my answer on how i read the JSON file. check that out

Comment: did not work both in 7545 or 8545 still the same issue.

Comment: Thats very strange. its working for me with the same settings. This error is kind of broad and usually happens due to many reasons like network connection or providing wrong values. First open your Metamask and make sure its not closed. Delete the files in build folder. Then run these commands in the same order again after running ganache-cli 1) truffle compile 2) truffle migrate --reset all. The contract address of TodoList will be shown in output console. Copy and paste that value. Also check my edited answer and replace that code in your truffle.config file.

Comment: I think maybe the issue is that the compiler does not generate the ABI correctly or the version plays a role in it. ! I really copy the ABI manoly from the Json file and the address but the issue still there .

Comment: Dont copy the ABI manually. Read the ABI like i mentioned in my answer. just read it from JSON file. Just copy the address of contract manually after deployment

Comment: One thing you might have to change is the path of the file to TodoList.json. That depends on the structure of your project directory. find the correct path of TodoList.json and if its different, replace it in this line: const TodoList = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('(path-to-buildfolder)/TodoList.json', 'utf8'))

Comment: This is what I did .
 1- but the truffle-config.js file is like the one you wrote . 2- run the ganache-cli 3- run react app and connect the Metamask with the first private key . 4- delete the build folder and compile the truffle and then migrate it . call the ABI  from the JSON file and Copy the first account from the ganache-cli terminal which is the same account that connects the Metamask . but still show me the same issue . :"(
I know I am bothering you . Thank you for everything .

Comment: And I note that the ABI changes from the one I had before , after changing the truffle-confilg.js file .

Comment: Hang on. There is a difference between account address and Contract address. Make sure you are giving it the contract address which has been recently deployed. Check my edited answer again for that information. 
ABI is supposed to be same every time you compile the contracts unless you change something in contract. And its not about bothering. i am sure we are all here to ask questions and get answers. But what happens is sometimes we just need more information and might ask you to try and check certain things to make it work. Like i said, this issue is broad so many things need to be ok.

Comment: Thank you So much , It works now all the issue was as you said the contrants address . I can not thank you enough .

Comment: Nice. and you are welcome. Just Edit your question and add another line about what the issue was. In that way it would be easier for others to find out. Another piece of advice is to read values either directly or from the file. In that way the code is less error prone. For example truffle provides a nice functionality of just simply getting the ABI and Address of deployed contracts from the deployed instance. Read more about it here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/how-to-know-the-contract-address-which-truffle-is-deploying-with

Comment: having  same issue, and the contract is working fine in remix but not working in clientside integration in my `create-react-app`....

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to re-run `truffle migrate --reset` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rinkeby: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(
          `dfsfsd,artist,test,hour,test,tse,wish,police,trade,gfh,sfdf,ssfsd`, // array of private keys(use yours get from metamask or recover)
          `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}` // Url to an Ethereum node
        )
      },
      networkCheckTimeout: 10000,
      gas: 5000000,
      gasPrice: 25000000000,
      network_id: 4
    }
```